# grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, details="Received message larger than max

Tags: grpc, tensorflow-serving

I built a segmentation model in keras and wanted to run the model in tensorflow serving. Currently I am able to export the model and run the model server, but the output is too big when I ran the client.py file. The error is:

```
  File "/home/.../serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/car_mask/mask_client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/car_mask/mask_client.py", line 47, in <module>
    result = stub.Predict(request, 10.0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 310, in __call__
    self._request_serializer, self._response_deserializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/beta/_client_adaptations.py", line 196, in _blocking_unary_unary
    raise _abortion_error(rpc_error_call)
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, details="Received message larger than max (4194349 vs. 4194304)")
```

How to solve this? Is there a way to add any grpc options to increase message size in client.py file? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
import grpc.beta.implementations
from grpc._cython import cygrpc

def insecure_channel(host, port):
        channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
            target=host if port is None else '%s:%d' % (host, port),
            options=[(cygrpc.ChannelArgKey.max_send_message_length, -1),
                     (cygrpc.ChannelArgKey.max_receive_message_length, -1)])
        return grpc.beta.implementations.Channel(channel)
```

from [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/13497)